# Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a stored procedure that `select * from book table` , using sub query my query is

```
USE [library]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[report_r_and_l]    Script Date: 04/17/2013 12:42:39 ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[report_r_and_l]
@fdate date,
@tdate date,
@key varchar(1)
as

if(@key='r')

    select * 
    from dbo.books 
    where isbn =(select isbn from dbo.lending where (act between @fdate and @tdate) and (stat ='close'))

else if(@key='l')

    select * 
    from dbo.books 
    where isbn =(select isbn from dbo.lending where lended_date between @fdate and @tdate)
```

I know sub query is return more than one query to main query , But i don't know how to avoid this error, can any one help me ?

Comment: Apparently that `select isbn` returns more than one value. You could use `where isbn IN (select isbn ...`

Comment: Use `select top 1 isbn ...` or `select max(isbn) ...`. Even if you know only one row will be returned, sql-server doesn't know, because the error message is based on a statical analysis of the command, but not based on the real data.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that these two queries are each returning more than one row:

```
select isbn from dbo.lending where (act between @fdate and @tdate) and (stat ='close')
select isbn from dbo.lending where lended_date between @fdate and @tdate
```

You have two choices, depending on your desired outcome.  You can either replace the above queries with something that's guaranteed to return a *single* row (for example, by using `SELECT TOP 1`), OR you can switch your `=` to `IN` and return multiple rows, like this:

```
select * from dbo.books where isbn IN (select isbn from dbo.lending where (act between @fdate and @tdate) and (stat ='close'))
```

Comment: I got that my friend,Thankz. I want to know one thing about this , only one is in books table refer to selected isbn , i want to select isbn from lending table,lend_no from lending table sudent_name from student table refer to index number in the lending table , how to retrive multiple rows from multiple tables??

Comment: No, the schema from the original question has `lended_date`. Actual defined schema beats good grammar every time, no matter how pedantic you want to be.

Comment: This is really the most concise and understandable description of IN that I have seen, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Use `In` instead of `=`

```
 select * from dbo.books
 where isbn in (select isbn from dbo.lending 
                where act between @fdate and @tdate
                and stat ='close'
               )
```

or you can use `Exists`

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM  books   t1 
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM dbo.lending t2 WHERE t1.isbn = t2.isbn and
                t2.act between @fdate and @tdate and t2.stat ='close' )
```

Comment: SET atRate1 = (SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM RateCode t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RateAmount t2 WHERE t1.RateCode = t2.RateCode AND t1.CountryCode = @CCode AND t1.ModuleCode = @MCode))

i am getting error on t2.*

Answer (score 4):

You can use IN operator as below

```
select * from dbo.books where isbn IN
(select isbn from dbo.lending where lended_date between @fdate and @tdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using operator 'IN' helps

USE [library]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[report_r_and_l]    Script Date: 04/17/2013 12:42:39 ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[report_r_and_l]
@fdate date,
@tdate date,
@key varchar(1)
as

if(@key='r')

    select * 
    from dbo.books 
    where isbn IN (select isbn from dbo.lending where (act between @fdate and @tdate) and (stat ='close'))

else if(@key='l')

    select * 
    from dbo.books 
    where isbn IN (select isbn from dbo.lending where lended_date between @fdate and @tdate)
```