# this returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I run the following query:

```
create function passs (@studentid nvarchar(50),@courseid nvarchar(50))
returns char
as
begin
declare @k char
if((select Grades.grade from Grades where Grades.Courses_id=@courseid AND 
Students_id=@studentid) >60)
set @k='pass'
else
set @k='no pass'
return @k
end
```

when i run this :

```
select Grades.Courses_id,dbo.pass(Grades.Students_id,Grades.Courses_id) 
,Grades.Students_id,Grades.grade from Grades
```

i got this

> > Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> >     Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I think the error is pretty obvious.  You need to explain what to do.  Also tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053907/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-subquery-foll)

Comment: You're getting more than one grade for the student/course combination.  What do you want to do if they got `50` in one row and `70` in another row?  Take their lowest grade, highest grade, average grade, something else?

Comment: You could use [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to determine if the student has _any_ grade for the class that exceeds `60`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what to do when a student has more than one grade for the same class -- that is the error you are getting.

Here is one possibility:

```
create function passs (@studentid nvarchar(50), @courseid nvarchar(50))
    returns varchar(255)
as
begin
    declare @k varchar(255);

    select @k = (case when min(g.grade) > 60 then 'pass' else 'no pass' end)
    from grades g
    where g.Courses_id = @courseid 
      AND g.Students_id = @studentid

    return @k;
end;
```

Notes:

- Declared the length of the return string -- your values have more than one character.
- Declared the length of `@k`.
- Combined the logic into a single query.
- Use `min()` to reduce the query return to a single row to avoid your specific problem.

Comment: I think should be `MAX(g.grade)`, student wont take the same course again if already pass it the first time